# Hilbert space inequality in series expansion coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

In the context of some quantum-mechanical problem, there occurs a series development which gives the dependence of an "energy-type" eigenvalue  $\varepsilon$ on some parameter $Q$. $\Psi_i$ are vectors in a
Hilbert space, that are eigenvectors of a symmetric (real) operator $\hat{H}(Q)$ that depends parametrically on $Q$.

The eigenvalues of $\hat{H} = \hat{H}(Q=0)$ in increasing order with $i$ are $\varepsilon_i^0 \le 0$. With that one can express the dependence of $\varepsilon$ on $Q$ assuming $\Psi_i$ form a complete basis 
like
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varepsilon(Q) = & \varepsilon_0^0 + c_1 Q + \frac{1}{2} c_2 Q^2 + \mathcal{O}(Q^3) \\
                 = & \varepsilon_0^0 + \\
                 + & <{\Psi_0|\frac{\partial\hat{H}}{\partial Q}|\Psi_0}> Q + \\
                 + & \frac{1}{2} \Bigg(<{\Psi_0|\frac{\partial^2\hat{H}}{\partial Q^2}|\Psi_0}> + 2 \sum_{i>0}\frac{<{\Psi_0|\frac{\partial\hat{H}}{\partial Q}|\Psi_i}>^2}{\varepsilon_0^0 - \varepsilon_i^0} \Bigg) Q^2\\
                 + & \mathcal{O}(Q^3).
\end{eqnarray*}
(this is something called perturbation expansion, but should be assumed valid)

I am interested in the second order term. The first summand in there shall be assumed to be positiv:
\begin{equation*}
S_1 = <{\Psi_0|\frac{\partial^2\hat{H}}{\partial Q^2}|\Psi_0}>\;\;\; > 0.
\end{equation*}
The second one
\begin{equation}
S_2 = 2 \sum_{i>0}\frac{<{\Psi_0|\frac{\partial\hat{H}}{\partial Q}|\Psi_i}^2>}{\varepsilon_0^0 - \varepsilon_i^0} < 0
\end{equation}
is negative since
\begin{equation*}
\varepsilon_i^0 \le \varepsilon_j^0 < 0,
\end{equation*}
for $ i < j$.

> I am interested to see in which cases $$S_1 + S_2 > 0$$
>   would hold.

In particular it would be interesting to see if when can impose conditions on the terms in $S_2$ s.t. $S_1 + S_2 > 0$ would follow.

Conditions on $S_2$ which are given and should be used are

- $<\Psi_0|\frac{\partial\hat{H}}{\partial Q}|\Psi_0>$ = 0.
- $|S_2|$ is large in general
- $ |\frac{<{\Psi_0|\frac{\partial\hat{H}}{\partial Q}|\Psi_1}>^2}{\varepsilon_0^0 - \varepsilon_1^0}|$ is large.
- assumptions on $|{\varepsilon_0^0 - \varepsilon_1^0}|$ can be made
- $Q$ belongs to a generator representation of the symmetry group of $\hat{H}$

I fail to see if such assumptions could possibly imply anything in general on the relative size of $S_1$ and $S_2$, but I can imagine that having informations on all of the summands in $S_2$ could have implications on $S_1$ in the way that $\Psi_0$ is a kind of orthogonal complement on the subspace spanned by $\Psi_i$ with $i>0$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "some parameter Q" and "Q  belongs to a generator representation of the symmetry group of H^"?

Comment: @KeithMcClary: It transforms like $x$ or $y$ or $z$.

Comment: @KeithMcClary: $Q\in\Bbb R^n$, but for simplicity can be treated like a real number ($n=1$) and the operator $\hat{H}$ is a function of $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$\hat{H}(Q) = H + QV +Q^2 W$$ then $S_1 = \langle \Psi_0 | W |\Psi_0\rangle $, so you can satisfy your condition by choice of $W$.

If the perturbation expansion is assumed valid then we might as well assume that an expansion of $\hat{H}(Q)$ in powers of $Q$ is also valid, so your condition just depends on the relative size of the first and second terms.

Comment: Thank you very much for your considerations! Would you agree then, to conclude that these 5 conditions are not sufficient to show that $$ |S_2| > |S_1| $$ holds? I have feared that, but its disappointing. I would be searching for 'minimal' general conditions, s.t. this inequality is implied.

Comment: sorry $$|S_1| > |S_2|$$

Comment: Suppose you replace $W$ with $W + wI$ where $I$ is the identity operator. Then you can make $S_2$ whatever you want by varying $w$. But this merely adds a constant to $\hat{H}$, which moves the whole spectrum up or down. Thus you are solving the same problem with different looking perturbation series, one of which may satisfy your condition and another not. I don't see why your condition should have any significance.